# Arrendondar os valores obtidos

Tags: javascript, revisão-de-código

Boa tarde, estou preparando, onde a matriz é formada pelo seguinte código:

```
var valores4='';
for(var LL =0;LL < noc*nol;LL++){
    for(var CC =0;CC < nol*noc;CC++){
        if(CC < noc*nol-1){
            valores4 += matriz_valores[LL][CC] + "\t";  
        }
        else{
            valores4 += matriz_valores[LL][CC] + "\n"; 
        }       

        var valores5 = '';
        for(var C1=0;C1<noc*noc;C1++){
          valores5 += matriz_cte[C1] + "\n";    
        }   


        console.log("Matriz com o Triângulo Inferior = 0: \n", valores4);
        console.log("Vetor [b] atualizados: \n", valores5);
    }
}
```

Ele ta copilando, porém as respostas obtidas são:

```
Matriz com o Triângulo Inferior = 0: 
 -1.975 0.263   0.250   0.000
0   -1.0316232911392405 0.017468354430379748    0.25
0   0   -1.4831279301246258 0.27348795654973657
0   0   0   -0.8578988360199865
```

Como poderei arrendondar as casas decimais???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No JavaScript para arredondar valores você tem 3 funções: Math.round, Math.ceil e Math.floor...

Porém se o seu valor assume algum carácter de string, o valor retornado por essas funções será um NaN(Not a Number), significa dizer que ele tentou fazer o casting(conversão de tipos) e mesmo assim não foi possível gerar um número, resultando em um NaN...

Para resolver isso você deve certifica-se que o tipo do valor é Number antes de usar a função, para isso você pode converter de duas formas:

- Utilizando o construtor Number:

  ```
  const digitosEmString = '51020';

  const digitosEmNumber = Number(digitosEmString);
  ```
- Utilizando o operador "+" na frente da string:

  ```
  const digitosEmNumber = +digitosEmString;
  ```

Comment: Consegui fazer aqui, só precisei fazer essa mudança no meu código: 
valores4 += Number(matriz_valores[LL][CC]).toFixed(3) +"\t";
E reduzi as casas decimais. 
Mais uma aprendizagem nessa área de de programação.